# How to make a barchart that doesn't start at y = 0

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, bar-chart, plotly-express

I want to make an barchart in python that has its own 'baseline', thus that the y-as doesn't start at 0 (as it usually does) but my chosen value.

Comment: can you show us the code you're using to plot the data and where you're stuck? are you using pandas plotting methods or matplotlib directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `bottom` argument to [`matplotlib.pyplot.bar`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html#matplotlib.pyplot.bar). This can be used in a `plt.bar` call or in `pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar`, which will pass keyword arguments through to matplotlib. The bottom argument will be added to all values in the dataframe, so you need to subtract it from the dataframe's values prior to plotting.

For example:

```py
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
years = np.arange(1880, 2022)
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'co2_concentration': (
        np.sin((years / 50 - 1)* np.pi) * 0.2
        + np.arange(len(years)) / len(years)
        + 56.7
    )},
    index=years,
)
base = 57.1
(df.co2_concentration - base).plot.bar(bottom=base, width=1)
plt.xticks(range(0, len(years), 20))
```

[image]